# Change location of APPDATA for SublimeText2 (windows)

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2

I have a HOME folder on a broken network share which is slow (don't ask) so I'd like to make ST2 honor a different folder for its `AppData\Roaming` stuff.

How can I do that? Setting `USERPROFILE` and `APPDATA` to a different location does not work.

Comment: If there is no configuration option, it is safe to assume, there is no way to change the location of that storage location.  In other words its likely configured, with no way to change it, to the /AppData/ directory which is a system variable.  **Changing where %AppData% points to would break your installation.**

Comment: Have you considered using symbolic links?